# What steps I can take to make this banner less crowded or with more empty space?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, website-design, critique, design-principles

I've tried many options but it's not working. Actually there are 3 groups of bottles in this banner and lots of text. So it is looking crowded. I tried small big size, placing copies here and there and many other options.

Also I feel the CTA button is also creating problem in terms of empty space. There is stuff nearby. I can't figure out a way to make this banner less crowded.

Here are last 2 options I tried:

[image]
[image]

The CTA I feel definitely has problem in terms of aesthetics.

I feel something is wrong that I can't figure out. I don't know what approach I should follow now. So:

i) Is the CTA distracting and crowded here or maybe less noticeable?

ii) Is the alignment of text and products okay in terms of aesthetics? 1st banner has center aligned text and products, 2nd banner has left aligned approach.

iii) Is the font size, weight and color *marrying* properly with objects near to it? Like **stop** with **alert** icon.

iv) Are the 3 groups of products covering more space then needed? I mean are the too big to be distracting the user to read other text and see CTA (The Learn How button)?

Comment: This is too broad in my opinion. You are asking other designers to design for you.

Comment: I didn't intend to do it. Can I fix the question somehow? Please let me know.

Comment: You need to ask direct, solvable questions rather than broad open "how should I change this to be better" questions.

Comment: Much better after edit

Comment: Here are some of my thoughts, for what it's worth. What is the purpose of the stop, bop, shop things?  In English "bop" is a kind of pop music dance, so I really don't get it. The stop sign looks like some kind of warning.  It's obviously a shopping site, so what's the point of it saying "Shop". I don't get the "Learn How" button either. Learn what? Learn how to shop? I'd just remove these items, and stick with the products.

Comment: @BillyKerr bop is for searching and comparing a brand product with their brand. Also, CTA is client requirement.

Comment: Maybe you need to speak to your client.  I don't think these elements communicate what the site is about.  That's just my opinion.

Comment: @BillyKerr stop bop shop is their main thing. They won't agree to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *primary* issue is that the "product images" have **nothing** to do with the slogan - stop - bop - shop

- How is a jar of Oil of Olay/Lux a "stop" image?
- Or body scrub a "bop" image?
- Or a bottle of body cleanser a "shop" image?

I feel, for reader clarity, the imagery needs to reflect the given step in the process. Otherwise, why not use images of puppies and kittens? They'd be almost as relatable to the underlying slogan.

Because of all this the CTA is **completely lost**. Alignment of text/images, font size, etc. are all irrelevant because the "path to purchase" is so indiscernible.

Honestly I have **no clue** what the actual CTA is.. to learn how? To shop? Since shop is a verb... the *natural* inclination will be that **it** is the CTA.

If, in fact, the push is to "Learn More" then it may be worth revisiting concept entirely to *deemphasize* the 3-steps-to-shopping appearance.

I would show something which clearly depicts "shopping" (cart/bag), then something which clearly depicts your web site, then something which clearly depicts "purchasing" (cashier/register). And put emphasis on the middle image, if that's the CTA, by making it larger, more prominent. -- It seems to me that you are assuming readers will understand all that you understand about the site.. they won't.

Comment: The product images are necessary because we want to say STOP and pause when you're going to buy your favorite product (on very left side). Then BOP on our site for this product to know if it is *good* or not. If not, which is of course (they have their reasons for it), SHOP our products (very right side). Makes sense?

Comment: The thinking is incorrect in my perception. **No part** of a jar of Oil of Olay and Lux says "Stop before you shop" to me. In short, **no one else** is going to think of things as you are.

Comment: I think you want to say for stop, the Lux product doesn't make sense because it can be a good brand (which it is). So we need to show the problem along with stop. Right? Why should they stop and bop?

Comment: **No** static product shot makes sense to me. If you *must* have a product image, then you need it as seen on a store shelf, or someone reaching for it.. in other words you need to *show* the "shopping" aspect since *that* is what is being referred to by "stop". Users will **not** know you are showing "bad products". You are assuming too much.

Comment: I would show something which *clearly* depicts "shopping" (cart/bag), then something which *clearly* depicts your web site, then something which *clearly* depicts "purchasing" (cashier/register). And put emphasis on the middle image, if that's the CTA, by making it larger, more prominent. -- It seems to me that you are assuming readers will understand all that you understand about the site.. they **won't**.

Comment: Okay. I got your point. Now the CTA is the button in corner.